# How well does Ubuntu 14 work on a vaio laptop or should i stick with 12.10

Tags: 14.04, 12.10, vaio

I was wondering how well 14.04 works with vaios or laptops for that matter? It took along time of tinkering with 12.10 to get all of the features that came with the laptop oem so losing all that hard work would seem a waste.  But dont get me wrong i love a good problem solving challenge.

Comment: Which one? What are the specifications?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbunutu! Please post other relevant information in the question (follow Mateo's queries).

Comment: 12.10 is unsupported, so you probably shouldn't stick with it regardless. You could install 12.04 instead if you really need an older version of Ubuntu, as it will be supported for a couple more years still. But either 12.04 or 14.04 are what you should "stick with."

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not use 12.10, as that is an unsupported release.  Using it would be bad for your security, and the security of others.

You *could* use 12.04, as despite being older that release has long term support and therefore will continue to get security updates for a long time.

However, I would not recommend it for the reason you've given.  Having older hardware is generally not a good reason to use an older release.  Ubuntu itself is designed to be able to run on some pretty old hardware, and with each new version release, in theory, its hardware support should become better, not worse.

If your system specs struggle to run Ubuntu smoothly, it would be a better idea to run a more minimal version of Ubuntu (such as Xubuntu/Ubuntu with XFCE), or another distribution more tailored to older hardware or poorer specs, than to run an outdated version of Ubuntu.  If you run an outdated version of Ubuntu, you'll be frustrated by older versions of software, poorer support for newer peripherals, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check how well Ubuntu 14.04 performs on your laptop, try the live version. Probably it would be slightly slower, but you can check the support for your hardware.

Comment: What makes you say it would be slower? What in particular would have gone backwards in terms of performance?

Comment: @neon_overload: I was just thinking that it would be run from an USB stick instead of having it installed on HDD and if he tries to use persistent storage it may seem slower during writing data.

Comment: Oh I see, right.